# How to configure Debian 12 to sleep without requiring password on i3wm

Tags: linux, debian

I recently upgraded to Debian 12 and find that after a period of inactivity a lock screen requires me to enter my password to unlock. I'm using my home pc and don't need that behaviour, however after trying to find the answer on-line I still don't know how to disable it. Please can I request kind suggestions on how to fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the [default config
file](https://github.com/i3/i3/blob/stable/etc/config.keycodes#L28), you
will see it has a line

```
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- i3lock --nofork
```

This uses `xss-lock` to listen for events including the X11 server using your
[DPMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling) (Display Power Management Signaling) settings to turn off video after
an idle time. It then runs `i3lock` to lock the screen and require your
password when the server uses DPMS to turn the video back on.

You can simply comment out this line with a `#` to not run the command. It applies to suspend and hibernate events too.

There are other programs that can call `i3lock`, like
[xautolock](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/I3#Screensaver_and_power_management) which you might have in your config file instead.